# How would i delete a listitem from a listview?

Tags: android, eclipse, listitem

The Listitem would not be retrieved from the db. It is passed over from another class.

Comment: Please Elaborate your question?

Comment: lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lvItems));
     lView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)

My Array of list items: private String lvItems[] = { "Pay-As-You-Roam", "International Roaming"};


public void remove()
{
    pos = lView.getCheckedItemPosition(); 
    if(pos == 0)
     { /*REMOVE ITEM*/  }
}

Comment: I'm hoping to remove that particular item when
[if(pos == 0)]

pos = lView.getCheckedItemPosition();

Comment: You cannot remove items from an `ArrayAdapter` when you use a Java array as the data source. You *can* remove items from an `ArrayAdapter` when you use an `ArrayList` as the data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "delete a listitem from a listview". You modify the data held by the `ListAdapter` that is supporting the `ListView`. If the adapter is an `ArrayAdapter`, call `remove()` on the `ArrayAdapter`. If the adapter is a `CursorAdapter`, remove the item from the database and `requery()` the `Cursor`. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you use a SimpleAdapter which takes an ArrayList.Then you update your list by removing what you want to remove & just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().Like:

```
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list =new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.newentrypagelayout);
        //create base adapter for listview
        adapter= new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                list,
                R.layout.custom_list_row,
                new String[] {"pen","price","color"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2, R.id.text3}

                );
            populateList();
            setListAdapter(adapter);


}

public void populateList()
{      
sHashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp.put("pen","MONT Blanc");
            temp.put("price", "200.00$");
            temp.put("color", "Silver, Grey, Black");
            list.add(temp);
            HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp1.put("pen","Gucci");
            temp1.put("price", "300.00$");
            temp1.put("color", "Gold, Red");
            list.add(temp1);
            HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp2.put("pen","Parker");
            temp2.put("price", "400.00$");
            temp2.put("color", "Gold, Blue");
            list.add(temp2);
            HashMap<String,String> temp3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp3.put("pen","Sailor");
            temp3.put("price", "500.00$");
            temp3.put("color", "Silver");
            list.add(temp3);
            HashMap<String,String> temp4 = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp4.put("pen","Porsche Design");
            temp4.put("price", "600.00$");
            temp4.put("color", "Silver, Grey, Red");
            list.add(temp4);

}
now if you need to delete an item.Get the selected index(the item that has been selected) remove it from the array list & call the method I told before.Like:

public void itemDeleteButtonClicked(View v)
     {
            int index=itemsListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
            list.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     }
```